# jQuery Price Countdown in relation to dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

Sadly I'm not a jQuery/JavaScript guru and I'm stumped with a problem.

In short, there's going to be an event where the price of a few fixed items goes down by the minute between two dates.

For example:

```
2012 07 25 - $1500 -> 2012 08 01 - $1000
```

And my problem is I don't even know where to start with making this a real-time countdown. Only the price is needed to appear. Any help, pointers, alternatives would be a great help.

Thanks to the replies I was able to create a solution. Sadly the pure JS version which Esailija supplied didn't want to work, but based on that I was able to create a php/ajax solution for this. Yes, I know this will put a strain on the server, but the JS version showed a whole new set of numbers not defined in the range, but php with the same formula produced valid results. Below you can find the full php code for this.

```
<?php

$dateStart = strtotime("16 july 2012 00:00");
$dateEnd = strtotime("18 july 2012 9:30");
$curDate = strtotime("now");

$startPrice = 3628000;
$endPrice = 3499000;

$progress = ($curDate - $dateStart) / ($dateEnd - $dateStart);

$curPrice = $startPrice - ($startPrice-$endPrice) * $progress;

$curPrice = round($curPrice);

if ($dateStart > $curDate) {
   echo $startPrice;
} elseif ($curDate >= $dateEnd) {
   echo $endPrice;
} else {
   echo $curPrice;
}

?>
```

Comment: Maybe you can provide a little bit of code in order we got matter to work with.. Use JSFiddle to hold your example code..

Comment: What do you mean didn't want to work? Can you provide jsfiddle where the js one doesn't work?

Comment: @Esailija I've used the fiddle you've posted, played around the dates, and it only showed 1500, no matter the date interval set. Also when implemented, the progress val's value was around -5 or higher, and the result price was ~7500 once the if/else was removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get price like this:

```
function getPrice() {
    var startDate = Date.UTC(2012,06,25,0,0,0,0),
        endDate = Date.UTC(2012,07,01,0,0,0,0),
        startPrice = 1500,
        endPrice = 1000,
        rightNow = +new Date,
        progress,
        price;

    progress = ( rightNow - startDate ) / ( endDate - startDate );

    if( progress < 0 ) {
        price = startPrice;
    }
    else if( progress >= 1) {
        price = endPrice;
    }
    else {
        price = startPrice - Math.abs(startPrice-endPrice) * progress;
    }
}
```

If right now is less than startDate, price is 1500.
If right now is more than endDate, price is 1000
If right now is between, it is calculated

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5v4yh/1/

Demo uses `2012 07 10 - $1500 -> 2012 07 15 $1000` so it's in the calculation phase

Comment: I don't understand why you set the start and end using UTC, but then use a local date for right now. It will be offset from the others by the local timezone offset.

Comment: @RobG [`+new Date` is not the local time, it gives ms since epoch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime). It's just an integer. The other `new Date`s were redundant and I removed them.

Comment: I should clarify that it's the local time in the sense that if the machine is set for example 10 years behind it will give that. But it's not the local time according to the local timezone.